# Modifying a template part don't do anything

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I try to modify a theme in WP and I just noticed that modifying a template part doesn't do anything. How is that possible? Tried on different browser to check if its cached and its not, how do I modify a theme part?

I'm using Academia Theme with LearnPress Plugin. I've made a Child theme and I'm trying to modify a file that is a theme part called content-course_list.php which is exactly the html that appears in the segment I want to modify. I just try to change a simple text that is "Read more". I found it, changed it and it doesn't update. I even put it in the child theme folder to make sure it gets it from there and nothing..

I don't use any cache plugins and the host is local (xampp).

Comment: More information would be required to help you find the exact file you need to edit or to identify why it is not updating. The WP templating engine is very conditional and there are usually more caching layers than just the local browser cache. Some relevant information may be: what them you are using, if you have a child theme active, any caching plugins in place you know about and possibly even your hosting package (as many hosts offer multiple cache layers including OPcode caching and object storage).

Comment: Thanks for the tips on how to improve the question. I've put the details in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the theme has a "core" plugin (academia-core) as well, where its using some shortcode templates for parts of the website. I managed to find the text by its css class (found with chrome inspect in the page) while I searched in all the php files from theme and plugins. I hope this answer helps someone in the future.

Comment: Hey, I'm glad you figured this out. If this is the correct answer to your question you can mark it as such. It doesn't matter that it's your own answer, this is the correct answer :)